# Achieving a more toned-down title format

Tags: sectioning, formatting

I love the title and section format on [this](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~amathew/verd.pdf) paper, as seen below. I think I remember seeing it in other places as well, which suggests to me it is a popular format.

[image]

Contrast this with the usual title and section format, that looks like this

[image]

Is anyone aware if there is a quick way to achieve the former style?

Comment: `amsart` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As David Carlisle has already suggested in a comment, the article whose appearance you like was generated with the `amsart` document class. The following code fully reproduces the first few lines of the screenshot you posted:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\title{Verdier Duality}
\author{Akhil Mathew}
\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
Let $M$ be a smooth, compact oriented manifold of dimension $n$, and let $k$ be a field. 
Recall that there is a natural pairing in singular cohomology
\end{document}
```